# UILabel won't register line spacing property

Tags: ios, uilabel

For some reason this code (the bold text in particular) doesn't change the line spacing of the text at all:

```
UIFont* customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:70];
NSString * text = @"Their \nIdeas";

**NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragrahStyle.lineSpacing = 30;
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];**

UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 70, viewWidth, 180)];
lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl1.textColor = grayColor;
lbl1.numberOfLines = 2;
lbl1.attributedText = attributedString;
lbl1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
lbl1.text = text;
[lbl1 setFont:customFont];
[view addSubview:lbl1];
[lbl1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.35)];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line ,

```
lbl1.text = text;
```

You are assigning a non attributed string just after assigning the attributed string which contains all line spacing data. Remove above line then your code will work.

And if you are using a large value for line spacing, make sure your label's height is enough to display the second line.